# Randomised column loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to build a data frame where I have a series of columns which contain a random assignment of another column. The data has some structure which needs to be maintained. Namely I want to randomise the assignment of **L** many time over, while maintaining the structure in **V**. I want to take a dataframe that looks like this;

```
  L B V    A
1 1 1 2 10.9
2 1 1 2  6.5
3 1 1 2  8.6
4 1 1 3 11.1
5 1 1 4 13.1
6 1 1 6 11.5
```

And create this;

```
     ID L B V    A R1 R2 R3 R4 R5
1 1_1_2 1 1 2 10.9 27 20 19  6 26
2 1_1_2 1 1 2  6.5 27 20 19  6 26
3 1_1_2 1 1 2  8.6 27 20 19  6 26
4 1_1_3 1 1 3 11.1  6 28  4 26 26
5 1_1_4 1 1 4 13.1 16  2  6 14 32
6 1_1_6 1 1 6 11.5 17 21  3 11 25
```

I can do this manually using the below script, but I wonder if there is a smooth way to make this automated, because I want to do it for hundreds of randomisations to make columns R1, R2, R3.. R*n* (so a loop to do this would be preferred to manual repetition of the code).

```
# Example Data Frame #
df = data.frame(sample(1:33, 1000, replace = T), sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T), sample(1:9, 1000, replace = T), round(rnorm(1000, 10, 2),1))
colnames(df) = c("L", "B", "V", "A")
df = transform(df,id=as.numeric(factor(df$V)))
df = data.frame(as.factor(df[,1]),as.factor(as.numeric(df[,2])),as.factor(df[,5]),as.numeric(df[,4]))
colnames(df) = c("L","B","V","A")
df = df[order(df$L, df$B, df$V),]
rownames(df) = NULL
head(df)

# ID #
df$ID = paste(df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], sep = "_")
ID = unique(as.vector(df$ID))

# R1 #
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID)); colnames(ID2) = c("ID","R1")
df = merge(df, ID2)
df$R1 = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(df$R1), split="_"))[,1])

# R2 #
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID)); colnames(ID2) = c("ID","R2")
df = merge(df, ID2)
df$R2 = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(df$R2), split="_"))[,1])

# R3 #
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID)); colnames(ID2) = c("ID","R3")
df = merge(df, ID2)
df$R3 = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(df$R3), split="_"))[,1])

# R4 #
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID)); colnames(ID2) = c("ID","R4")
df = merge(df, ID2)
df$R4 = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(df$R4), split="_"))[,1])

# R5 #
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID)); colnames(ID2) = c("ID","R5")
df = merge(df, ID2)
df$R5 = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(df$R5), split="_"))[,1])
```

How can I create a loop which will make this happen in *n* number of columns?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this randomization, can't you just do something like `df[paste0("R", 1:5)] <- sample(33, 5)[rep(1:5, each = nrow(df))]`?

Comment: no, that maintains **L** structure, not **V**. What I mean by that is I want to get all rows which have the same **V** value to be assigned the same randomly selected value of **L**.

Comment: In you example *all* the values are the same for both `V` and `L`. so maybe make your example more reasonable?

Comment: Ah, perhaps because there is a large number of replicates per value of L and V, so head() only shows one combination - I'll edit the script to make sure that it becomes clearer above

Comment: We don't need a data set of 13K rows. Just a representative example of 10 rows should be fine IMO

Comment: So you want to create 5 new columns where there is a unique sample set per each combination of `L` and `V`?

Comment: I want to create a couple of hundred such columns. In the head() of the example you see the first 6 rows contain 4 different values of **V** (2,2,2,3,4,6) - for each randomisation column each value of **V** will get assigned a randomly selected value of **L**, within each column all rows where **V** matches they will have the same value of **L**, but this can and should vary between randomisations.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I got to an answer - see below, thanks for your help along the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from the above code I finally got to an answer:

```
# ID #
df$ID = paste(df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], sep = "_")
ID = unique(as.vector(df$ID))

n = 5
Rs     = as.vector(rep(NA,n))

for(i in 1:n){
 Rs[i] =     paste("R",i, sep = "")
 }
Rs

for(i in 1:n){
df[,5+i] = NA
colnames(df)[5+i] = paste(Rs[i])
ID = unique(as.vector(df$ID))
ID2 = data.frame(ID, sample(ID))
ID2 = merge(df, ID2)
df[5+i] = as.factor(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(ID2[,6+i]), split="_"))[,1])
}
head(df)
```

Gives the result:

```
  L B V    A    ID R1 R2 R3 R4 R5
1 1 1 2 10.1 1_1_2 21 12 27  4 26
2 1 1 4  7.7 1_1_4  7 29  2  9 10
3 1 1 5  9.7 1_1_5 27 27  3  1 22
4 1 1 5  8.3 1_1_5 27 27  3  1 22
5 1 1 7  9.5 1_1_7 13 15 32 19 11
6 1 1 7 12.4 1_1_7 13 15 32 19 11
```